# Chef - Override templates in third party cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I'm using the including the default PHP cookbook within my cookbook but I need to set a different `include_path` for PHP but it's not an option that I can set.

Is there any way I can over-write the default PHP.ini template with my own template from my cookbook?

Answer (score 2):

The way that I found was to override the resource on the PHP cookbook from a cookbook that I had developed.

```
include_recipe "php"

begin
  t = resources(:template => "/etc/php.ini")
  t.source "php.ini.erb"
  t.cookbook "my_cookbook"
rescue Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound
  Chef::Log.warn "Could not find template /etc/php.ini to modify"
end
```